# Why does Moriarty owe Sherlock a fall?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

Why does Moriarty owe Sherlock a fall? I mean why did he specifically emphase that he owed Sherlock a fall? What happened between them?

Comment: You might want to provide a little more context to your question. What movie/show are you talking about? What episode are you talking about (if it's a TV-show)? When did he say that?

Comment: You can easily see the movie on the tags and anyone who watched the movie know the this quote.

Comment: is this about movie as this tag is for tv series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-did-Moriarty-mean-when-he-told-Sherlock-I-owe-you-And-what-exactly-was-the-final-problem-Moriarty-talked-about) :

> Moriarty promised way back at the swimming pool that he was going to
>   kill Sherlock eventually. And not only kill him, but burn him
>   completely in the process, if Sherlock didn't back off and leave him
>   alone.
>
> "I owe you" is simply a reminder of that threat. Similarly, the final
>   problem, the one about which Moriarty says, "I told you, but did you
>   listen" is, literally, Stayin' Alive, as Moriarty says when Sherlock
>   comes to find him on the St. Bart's roof. Sherlock's the only thing
>   that makes Moriarty's life interesting, but he can't let Sherlock live
>   because he'll keep interfering.
>
> Of course, there's also the theory that Jim was planning the Fall way
>   back from the very, very beginning, right down to planning the precise
>   moment he'd get the phone call from Irene Adler at the swimming pool
>   that resolved his standoff with Sherlock. [More...](https://www.quora.com/What-did-Moriarty-mean-when-he-told-Sherlock-I-owe-you-And-what-exactly-was-the-final-problem-Moriarty-talked-about)